# Returning an empty item in a C function call

Tags: c, pointers, null

I want to return the last in a stack. Something like the following:

```
Item* get_last_item()
{
    if (item_stack_size == 0) {
        // return <nothing> ?
    }  else {
         return ItemStack[item_stack_size-1];
    }
}
```

What is the suggested practice when returning the equivalent of a `null` value if the stack is empty? Should this usually issue a hard error? Something like a value of `(Item*) 0`, or what's the suggested practice for doing something like this? My first thought was to do something like this, but I'm not sure if there's a better way:

```
Item* get_last_item()
{
    return (item_stack_size != 0) ? ItemStack[item_stack_size-1] : (void*) 0;
}
```

Comment: In general, for any function that returns a value, or can fail, you have two choices: (1) return an "out of band" value, or (2) return a separate, success/fail status separate from the returned value.  Both approaches have their pluses and minuses.  For pointers, `NULL` is an excellent out-of-band value you can use.  For characters, `EOF`.  But for arbitrary integers, there often isn't a single value that can't also be legitimate.  Since your `get_last_item` function returns pointers, `NULL` might be  good choice -- as long as the caller is always careful to check for it!

Comment: @SteveSummit I see, thank you. Would you want to show an answer with both cases in a bit more detail?

Comment: No, not just now, I'm supposed to be working. :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit ha, ok fair enough! Is it ok to return `NULL` by itself, or does it need to be `(Item*) NULL` ?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 On my system (and probably on many systems too) `NULL` is defined as `((void *)0)`. And as of [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL): A null pointer constant may be converted to any pointer type; such conversion results in the null pointer value of that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For functions returning a pointer, a NULL pointer can be used as an *out of band* value( the caller of course should check the pointer for NULL, before dereferencing it):

---

```
Item *pop_last_item()
{
    if (!item_stack_size) {
        return NULL;
    }  else {
         return ItemStack[--item_stack_size];
    }
}
```